# Query examples in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql-server-2005, many-to-many

Wow, it's hard to find a simple explanation to this topic. A simple many-to-many relationship.

Three tables, tableA, tableB and a junction tableA_B.

I know how to set up the relationship, with keys and all, but I get a little confused when time comes to perform INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE queries....

Basically, what I am looking for is an example that shows:

1. How to get all records in TableA, based on an ID in TableB
2. How to get all records in TableB, based on an ID in TableA

3 How to INSERT in either TableA or TableB, and then make the appropriate INSERT in the junction table to make the connection..

I'm not looking for a solution to a specific project, just a few general examples that can be applied. Maybe you have something lying around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing I would do is recommend using an ORM like [Linq-To-Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) or [NHibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/343.html) which will give you object representations of your data-model which make it much simpler to handle complex things like many-to-many CRUD operations.

If an ORM isn't part of your tool set then here is how this would look in SOL.

```
Users       UserAddresses     Addresses
=======     =============     =========
Id          Id                Id
FirstName   UserId            City
LastName    AddressId         State
                              Zip
```

Our tables are joined like this:

```
   Users.Id -> UserAddresses.UserId
   Addresses.Id -> UserAddresses.AddressId
```

- All records in Users based on Addresses.Id

```
SELECT        Users.*
FROM            Addresses INNER JOIN
                         UserAddresses ON Addresses.Id = UserAddresses.AddressId INNER JOIN
                         Users ON UserAddresses.UserId = Users.Id
WHERE        (Addresses.Id = @AddressId)
```

- All records in Addresses based on Users.Id

```
SELECT        Addresses.*
FROM            Addresses INNER JOIN
                         UserAddresses ON Addresses.Id = UserAddresses.AddressId INNER JOIN
                         Users ON UserAddresses.UserId = Users.Id
WHERE        (Users.Id = @UserId)
```

Comment: This solved my problem with selecting, but I'm struggling a little with updating the junction table. What is the smartest way to do this? I'd have to set the WHERE clause to both the existing Userid and Addressid, right?
I've tried with temp tables, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Comment: Yes. You need to set the wehere clause to both the existing Userid and Addressid

Comment: @Micah What if I write the first query like this: 

`SELECT        Users.*
FROM            Users INNER JOIN
                         UserAddresses ON Users.Id = UserAddresses.UsersID INNER JOIN
                         Addresses ON UserAddresses.AddressId = Addresses.Id
WHERE        (Addresses.Id = @AddressId)`                                                     

Will it be okay and what will be returned?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE id IN (SELECT aid FROM ab WHERE bid = 1234)
```

or

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
JOIN ab ON a.id = ab.aid
WHERE ab.aid = 12345
```

To insert, that depends on your database (eg whether the primary keys are from sequences, auto-generated or generated in some other fashion or simply composite keys).  But you just need:

For that data:

```
INSERT INTO a VALUES (...)
```

For the relationship:

```
INSERT INTO ab VALUES (...)
```

Comment: Ok, so it's possible to do this with or without joins?

In the second example (with the join), is it necessary to write "SELECT a.*"

Comment: select where in () is usually slower than select where exists ()
select * from a where exists (select * from b where a.Id = b.aId and b.Id = 1234)

Answer (score 1):

To get all records in table A based on key in B, in english, you want the records in Table A which have a Join record with that TableB key 
(Assume tableA_B has two Foreign Key cols,  (TabAFK and TabBFK)

```
  Select * from TableA A
  Where pK In (Select Distinct TabAFK From tableA_B
                Where TabBFK = @TableBKeyValue)
```

Same thing for other direction

```
  Select * from TableB B
  Where pK In (Select Distinct TabBFK From tableA_B
                Where TabAFK = @TableAKeyValue)
```

To insert a new record, do a normal insert into TableA and TableB as necessary... Inserts into the join table (tableA_B) are just the two pks from the two main tables

```
   Insert TableA (pk, [other columns]) Values(@pkValue,  [other data)
   Insert TableB (pk, [other columns]) Values(@pkValue,  [other data)
```

---

-- Then insert into Join table for each association that exists...

```
  Insert tableA_B (TabAFK, TabBFK)  Values(@PkFromA,  @PkFromB)
```

Answer (score 0):

1)
select tableA.* from tableA join tableA_B on tableA.id = tableA_B.idA
where tableA_B.idB = somevalue

2) 
select tableB.* from tableB left join tableA_B on tableB.id = tableA_B.idB
where tableA_B.idA = somevalue

3) insert depends on your database, but insert into a, insert into b, and then insert into a_b; even with constraints on the tables it should work that way.

hint: don't use IN operator for 1/2