# Storing and retrieving objects with searchable array data in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, orm

Imagine you had a class like

```
class Person {
 public $id;
 public $name;
 public $cars = array();
}
```

Where `$cars` is an array of cars (e.g. `array('mercedes', 'toyota')`).

How would you store that data in the database so that the array can be searched (e.g. select all persons that have a Toyota) and the entirely filled objects are retrieved with the same query (e.g fetch all the other cars that belong to those persons too).

Edit:

By "storing the object" I meant its data.

Comment: You wouldn't store the `Object` in the database, you would create the `Object` from the data you retrieve from the database.  You would want at the least 2 tables, `person_tbl` with (`id`,`name`,`cars`) and `cars_tbl` with (`id`, `car`) and you would then do a query on these two tables.

Comment: I tried to do this by joining 2 tables, but the problem was that when the query contains "WHERE car.name = 'toyota'", only the toyota will be fetched, not the other cars that belong to this person.

Comment: Join the table twice, once to get all the cars, once to use your where clause

Comment: This may be just what I'm missing. Can you give an example? My query looks like this right now:

SELECT p.*, c.car AS car FROM {person} p INNER JOIN {person_car} pc ON pc.person_id = p.id INNER JOIN {car} c ON c.id = pc.car_id WHERE (c.car = 'toyota')

PS: It would be awesome if you could add it to "answers", because I think you will deserve an upvote from me :)

Comment: Thank you, I got it now. This causes some duplicates that I can get rid of with distinct. Wonder if it's the most efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Create a tables called `person` and  one called `car` and a linking table called `car_person`

```
  CREATE TABLE `car` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  CREATE TABLE `person` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


   CREATE TABLE `car_person` (
    `car_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`,`person_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Also, make a Car class in your PHP :

```
class Car {
  public $id;
  public $name;
 }
```

Then use the array of cars in the Person class is an array of car objects, not names....

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical [many to many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29). Example tables would be:

**person:**

```
id
name
```

**person_vehicle:**

```
id
person_id
car_id
```

**vehicle:**

```
id
manufacturer
```

You can find more design examples, as well as example queries, on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416565/query-examples-in-a-many-to-many-relationship).