# How to update table using many to many relations in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to update a table using many to many relations. I have three tables:

- users;
- badges;
- user_badge;

In the `users` table I have: `id`, `username` and `game_count`. In the badges table I have: `badge_id` and `badge_name`. The user_badge table has `id`, `user_id` and `badge_id`.

The `user_id` and `badge_id` in the `user_badge` table represent the `id` columns in the `users` and `badges` tables. These are used as foreign keys in the `user_badge` table.

I would like to update the `user_badge` table with the values from the other two tables: `users` and `badges`.

For example, table Users, have the following details.

```
id:1   username:john   game_count:1
```

Table badges has:

```
id:1   badge_name:firstbadge
```

So, when I apply a condition (e.g. `game_count=1`), the  `user_badge` 
 table should update its column with `user_id` from `users` and `badge_id` from the `badges` table.

Can someone help me with writing this query?

Comment: What did you tried show us the code

Comment: i dont know the query to update the table using many to many relation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query examples in a many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416565/query-examples-in-a-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some [additional research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried.